# Replaying SQL Server 2008 traces in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server

Whilst trying to replay trace SQL Server 2008 trace in SQL Server 2000 got this message:
"SQL Server Profiler cannot perform Replay on database servers earlier than the server used to generate the original trace data. Please use a later version of SQL Server.". 
Is it possible at all to replay SQL Server 2008 traces in SQL Server 2000?
Is there any third party software that convert traces?
Databases are exactly the same on both servers.
I already tried to change compatibility level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible in my opinion. Trace in SQL 2008 has different/additional events which weren't available in SL 2000.

Comment: What if got exactly the same set of events in both 2008 and 2000?

Comment: I will accept this answer, just to confirm the fact. I will try to ask experts personally though.